# abstract class takes attribute values from child class

Tags: php, oop

I noticed something strange I hope you can explain why it happens &  what does it called in php

Anyway  let assume I have 2 classes

```
abstract class parent {

    protected $test = ['parent'];
    public function __construct()
    {
        die(var_dump($this->test));
    }

}

class chile extends  parent{
    protected $test = ['child'];
}
```

as you see I'm trying to print test value in parent class but I get  child value
not parent ?

> die(var_dump($this->test)); returns "child" not parent value

why does it take child test value instead of parent  ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: I read this but it says  child Inherit from the parent, but in my case parent Inheriting from  child ??  also it's override the attribute value in the parent. it might lead to many issues

Comment: its happen because  there is using late static binding. You can read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php here in details.

Comment: No, if you do `$o = new chile;` then you are instantiating `chile` not `parent`.

Comment: But I'm not using static  in the classes also  I noticed it only happens when parent and child classes has same attributes name and the parent attribute is protected  then the parent will use child attribute and ignore the attribute the parent class

Comment: `$this` refers to the current object and the current object is of class `chile`. If you want the var in the class use `var_dump(self::$test)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver  So  if I instantiating chiled class then the parent will use child attributes instead of its own attributes like example above ?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works in all OOP languages as far as I know.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  I understand your point  but  if  I use $this  in parent class shouldn't it point to  same class (parent) ?

Comment: No, `$this` means current OBJECT and the OBJECT is of class `chile`.  If you didn't define it in `chile` then it would use the one in `parent`. If you did `$o = new parent;` then the current OBJECT would be of class `parent`.

Comment: Thank you very much , I need to study more about oop.    Best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a few steps back here. It seems you are confused with the `abstract` keyword here. An abstract class can't be an object. It does not represent something that can be instantiated.

> why does it take child test value instead of parent ?

In this case, it's because the parent was never an instance of an object to begin with. Being an abstract class, it must be extended to be of any use.

When you instantiate the child class with `new`, the child `protected $test` then takes precedence over the parent test property, which is expected oop behaviour.

From your comment:

> So if I instantiating chiled class then the parent will use child attributes instead of its own attributes like example above

It's not "child attribute" versus "parent attribute", they are **the same attribute**. There's no parent's test property and child's test property, upon being instantiated, the extending class overwrites its own test property (which is the same than the parent class).

Understand that extending means basically adding functionnality to a class, not creating a new one. For all intent and purposes, you should consider parent and child to be the same and only here.